# Symfony override configuration from the app/config.yml

Tags: symfony, configuration, doctrine

I have in my `app/config.yml` this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

Now I create my bundle and I want it to override some of this configuration:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
              Acme\UserBundle\Interfaces\User: Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User
```

I want to add this configuration without changing `app/config.yml`

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: to allow the bundle to work without extra configuration by user. (in that case user do not need to change configuration, he do not need to know anything - bundle itself configures everything. user only installs the bundle and uses it.)

Comment: Then why are you using resolve_target_entities ? This is especially done to permit end user to customize dependencies.

Comment: BTW, you can manipulate this config using compiler passes.

Comment: OR: by manipulating doctrine class metadata.

Comment: actually resolve_target_entities is used by my bundle, but it resolves target entities of another bundle. This is the purpose of my bundle - `resolve entities` and `bind` bundles. So I want him to do his designation by himself, without adding extra configuration to the app/config.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution by adding compiler pass:

```
class OrmResolverCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('orm.yml');

        $def = $container->findDefinition('doctrine.orm.listeners.resolve_target_entity');
        foreach ($container->getParameter('resolve_target_entities') as $name => $implementation) {
            $def->addMethodCall('addResolveTargetEntity', array( $name, $implementation, array() ));
        }
        $def->addTag('doctrine.event_listener', array('event' => 'loadClassMetadata'));
    }

}
```

And we also need to create `orm.yml` in the `Resources/config` directory inside our Bundle.

And finally register compiler pass inside controllerBundle class:

```
class MyAcmeBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new OrmResolverCompilerPass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now use [`PrependExtensionInterface`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html) for this:

```
class ThirisCartLogicCatalogExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{    
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $config = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config/config.yml'));

        foreach ($config as $key => $configuration) {
            $container->prependExtensionConfig($key, $configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code config.yml from your bundle will be unconditionally merged into global confuguration.

Please note, that configuration file you load [is not validated for syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596995/how-to-add-global-configuration-from-the-bundles-local-configuration-file) this way.

Comment: For me this function is not executed. Is there something else to do in order to make that happen?