# How to add global configuration from the bundle's local configuration file?

Tags: symfony

I have an application where business logic is split into bundles for easy management and extensions. Each bundle provides its entities, services, templates (if that is UI bundle) etc.

Entities should be registered to ORM to participate in commands like `./bin/console doctrine:schema:update`.

I'm using custom folder structure for my bundles so I don't have any root Entity folder in each bundle. So, I have to register entities using `doctrine.orm.mappings` configuration key.

I want each bundle to register its entities itself without putting references to them into global config.

So, I'm using `PrependExtensionInterface` for this in each bundle. My `prepend()` method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Allow an extension to prepend the extension configurations.
 *
 * @param ContainerBuilder $container
 */
public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $config = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config/config.yml'));

    foreach ($config as $key => $configuration) {
        $container->prependExtensionConfig($key, $configuration);
    }
}
```

My .yml looks like this:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
      mappings:
          thiris_cart_logic_auth_user:
              type: annotation
              dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/ThirisCart/Logic/AuthBundle/User/Model
              alias: Category
              prefix: ThirisCart\Logic\AuthBundle\User\Model
              is_bundle: false
```

It works very good except for one thing.
It looks, like the configuration I've read from .yml is not verified for correctness. It is just merged into global configuration without further questions.

So, the question is how to verify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer by looking through Symfony source.

If you look into [`Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PassConfig::__construct`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/PassConfig.php#L43) you will see, that first pass is [`MergeExtensionConfigurationPass`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php#L35), where `prepend()` is called. So, appended configuration will get verified.

But note, that Symfony caches configuration. And if you change your code in your prepend() method, you will have to `touch()` some of your config files as well or just invalidate config cache for your changes to have effect.